# Internal error in Ubuntu 13.10 / ProblemType: KernelOops / Package: linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic 3.11.0-19.33

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, error-handling

I'm a fresh user of (L)Ubuntu 13.10 . Every time I start a session I get multiple times an error message, the first lines of which read

```
ExecutablePath

/use/share/apport/apportcheckresume

Package

linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic 3.11.0-19.33

ProblemType

KernelOops
```

Sorry, but I haven't enough reputation points to post a screenshot.

Is it grave ? How can I fix it and get rid of this tons of crash reports ?

(I'm wondering if this has something to do with the fact that my laptop has a weird behaviour whenever at booting with no AC power supply: I always need to boot it twice. If you think this is relevant to the above issue, I can tell you more about it.)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that kernel 3.11.0-19.33 has some very strange issues (I am having power issues with it, other face wrong screen resolution, etc.). Try booting with the older kernel (advanced options in grub bootloader).