# How to identify the cause of a crash from the content of the /var/crash file?

Tags: crash

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

My computer crashes randomly. Everything freezes and the sound is stuck with a "shhhhhhhhh" loud sound.

I wondered if it was related to the onboard sound chip, disabled it but the problem remained. Same for the network controller.

I did a night long memtest that returned no error.

My google foo indicated me that I might find relevant info in the `/var/crash` folder and it seems to be indeed the case since the time/date matches the latest crash.

Here is its content:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Sun Aug 11 10:33:51 2019
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
 Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_uvm(OE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) 8250_dw intel_wmi_thunderbolt mxm_wmi snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp input_leds snd_hda_intel coretemp snd_hda_codec joydev snd_hda_core kvm_intel snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_rawmidi aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq drm_kms_helper glue_helper cryptd snd_seq_device drm snd_timer intel_cstate ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler fb_sys_fops snd intel_rapl_perf syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore idma64 virt_dma serio_raw mei_me sch_fq_codel
  intel_lpss_pci mei intel_pch_thermal binfmt_misc intel_lpss shpchp mac_hid wmi video acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 mii libahci pinctrl_sunrisepoint
 CPU: 5 PID: 5225 Comm: Web Content Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: MSI MS-7971/Z170-A PRO (MS-7971), BIOS 1.F0 10/19/2016
 RIP: 0010:set_page_dirty+0x2a/0xb0
 RSP: 0018:ffffb0a2444fbc30 EFLAGS: 00010282
 RAX: fdff9adb8baf04a8 RBX: ffffeab44fdd1d40 RCX: ffffeab44da28720
 RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f8951bcc000 RDI: ffffeab44fdd1d40
 RBP: ffffb0a2444fbc38 R08: ffffeab44fdd1d40 R09: ffff9adaead05a00
 R10: ffff9adbeefd3000 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: 80000003f7475867
 R13: ffff9adb133f8e60 R14: 00007f8951bcc000 R15: ffffb0a2444fbda8
 FS:  00007f898d755300(0000) GS:ffff9adbeed40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: 00007f8956a0f000 CR3: 000000034fa64001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
 DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
 DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
 Call Trace:
  unmap_page_range+0xa03/0xd00
  unmap_single_vma+0x7d/0xf0
  unmap_vmas+0x51/0xb0
  unmap_region+0xbd/0x130
  do_munmap+0x276/0x450
  vm_munmap+0x69/0xb0
  SyS_munmap+0x22/0x30
  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
 RIP: 0033:0x7f898c69bab7
 RSP: 002b:00007ffc34acd668 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000000b
 RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f890d811760 RCX: 00007f898c69bab7
 RDX: 00007f897b410bc0 RSI: 0000000000e11000 RDI: 00007f89518ef000
 RBP: 00007f890d811740 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f890d727574
 R10: 00007ffc34acd680 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 0000000000000000
 R13: 00007f890d758508 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00007f897ffb5525
 Code: 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 53 48 89 fb e8 de 84 01 00 48 8b 53 20 48 8d 4a ff 83 e2 01 48 0f 45 d9 48 85 c0 74 51 48 8b 4b 20 <48> 8b 40 70 48 8d 51 ff 83 e1 01 48 8b 40 18 48 0f 44 d3 48 8b 
 RIP: set_page_dirty+0x2a/0xb0 RSP: ffffb0a2444fbc30
 ---[ end trace 604eafcf9eccee21 ]---

Package: linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic 4.15.0-55.60
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-55-generic x86_64
```

Is there something to be interpreted from this?

Thanks!

Comment: See these for help: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333459, https://askubuntu.com/questions/443213/internal-error-in-ubuntu-13-10-problemtype-kerneloops-package-linux-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BIOS is way old at version 1.F0 from 10/19/2016.

Go to https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z170-A-PRO and download and install their updated BIOS version 7971v1K from 2018-07-16.

Comment: I just updated my bios to this latest version you suggested. I now wait & see if it fixes the issue. I will validate your answer in the upcoming days if I can confirm I have no more crashes . Thank you very much for your insight. :)

Comment: @Billybobbonnet status please...

Comment: 2 days without a crash, since it was 10 per day I think that the problem is solved :) Thank you!